# Split dataframe string (when string can hold n values of that cell variable), into multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, split

Currently working on a dataset with a lot of contact data, being Emails one of the variables.

A cell in the Emails column can have more than one email (1 to n) and they are all separated by a comma and a space.

For contacts with only two emails, the process would be quite straightforward. One can split the string and create a new column for that secondary email as follows

```
email_df[['Emails', 'SecondaryEmail']] = email_df['Emails'].str.split(', ', expand=True)
```

However this won't work with more than 2 emails. Therefore, I wonder what is the most efficient way to split the emails when the number of emails can go from 1 to n (in this case the n is limited to around 10 but that won't always be the case), into columns with only one email each (and different names each)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)[`Series.str.rsplit`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rsplit.html) with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for remove column `Email` after processing:

```
df = email_df.join(email_df.pop('Emails').str.split(', ', expand=True).add_prefix('Email'))
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael - it is exactly this. One note, for those that haven't tested, after this one might want to drop the column "Emails". If that is the case `df .drop('Emails', axis=1, inplace=True)`